# How to append stderr and stdout output to file in system2 R command?

Tags: r

I am trying to execute shell command from R (3.3.1 on Ubuntu) like this:

```r
system2(command="ls", 
        args=c("-l", "/etc/"), 
        stdout="/tmp/stdout.log", 
        stderr="/tmp/stderr.log", 
        wait=TRUE)
```

Unfortunately every time this is executed the contents of log files is overwritten. Can we somehow specify this to perform append instead of overwrite?

Comment: use `stderr=TRUE` to capture in a char vector and then write it to a file with `append=TRUE` ?

Comment: Unfortunately there is a known limit of 8095 bytes that can be captured that way. What if command outputs more data?

Comment: Then I don't see any option than a timestamped file. (Maybe a workaround could be using a `tempfile` as stdout/stderr from wich you can read from and write to your "central" log after ?

Comment: Damn. So wanted to be my mistake...

Comment: Quoting the doc: "If stdout = TRUE or stderr = TRUE, a character vector giving the output of the command, one line per character string. (Output lines of more than 8095 bytes will be split.)" you may just end up with more entries than lines, but a line over 8095 chars sounds unlikely to appear on most programs

Comment: TL;DR: the character vector is a solution if you don't mind getting two lines instead of one when they're more than 8095 character long)

Comment: Or `shell("ls -l /etc/  >> /tmp/lslog.log 2>&1", wait=TRUE)` ?

Comment: I know that shell or system stuff but kind of wanted to use system2 that alleviates all that mumbo jumbo... thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And this one is even better since it permits the use of more modern system command and permits doing clearer logging.

```r
result <- system2(command="ls", 
                  args=c("-l", "/etc/"), 
                  stdout="/tmp/stdout.log", 
                  stderr="/tmp/stderr.log", 
                  wait=TRUE)
now <- date()
cat(paste0("Executed: ", now, "\n"), file="/tmp/stdoutmain.log", append=TRUE)
file.append("/tmp/stdoutmain.log", "/tmp/stdout.log")
cat(paste0("Executed: ", now, "\n"), file="/tmp/stderrmain.log", append=TRUE)
file.append("/tmp/stderrmain.log", "/tmp/stderr.log")
```

Answer (score 0):

This performs the way I wanted...

```r
system(command="ls -l /etc/ >> /tmp/stdout.log 2>> /tmp/stderr.log", 
       wait=TRUE)
```